# Victory onClick event not updating fill color

Tags: javascript, reactjs, victory-charts

I am new to react and trying to use Victory within a react app to make a simple scatter plot. I was working through the examples and cannot get the interactive portion of the scatter plot to work.

Here is my App.js

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { VictoryScatter } from 'victory';
import {sampleData} from './data_holder'



class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
  <h3>Click Me</h3>
  <VictoryScatter
    style={{ data: { fill: "#c43a31" } }}
    size={9}
    labels={() => null}
    events={[{
      target: "data",
      eventHandlers: {
        onClick: () => {

          return [
            {
              target: "data",
              mutation: (props) => {
                const fill = props.style && props.style.fill;
                return fill === "black" ? null : { style: { fill: "black" } };
              }
            }, {
              target: "labels",
              mutation: (props) => {
                return props.text === "clicked" ?
                  null : { text: "clicked" };
              }
            }
          ];
        }
      }
    }]}
    data={sampleData}
  />
</div>

    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>,  document.getElementById('root'));

export default App
```

Sample data saved in .data_holder is here:

```
export const sampleData=[
      { x: 1, y: 2 },
      { x: 2, y: 3 },
      { x: 3, y: 5 },
      { x: 4, y: 4 },
      { x: 5, y: 7 }
    ]
```

The onClick event is happening (when I add a log statement in the onClick it is clearly shown), but the fill colors are not updating. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Did you find a solution for your issue? Because I tried to create a codesandbox (here: https://codesandbox.io/s/exciting-water-wnt6y?file=/src/App.js) and it seems to work.

Comment: Thanks for taking a look! No I haven't found a solution yet. I am wondering if it is specific to running the code in pycharm though. I'll be sure to update here if I find an answer.

Comment: Actually I literally just figured it out. Thanks you so much for causing me to look at it again. For some reason enabling strict mode within react removes the ability for the plot to update. I am trying to read more about strict mode to understand why, but it may be a while before I understand.

Answer (score 3):

Use `onPressIn` in place of `onClick` will work.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the issue is caused by enabling strict mode for the component in react. I am uncertain of why, but the plot is able to update once I remove strict mode from react. I will update here once I know the specifics of interaction.